# Defining and accessing JNDI variables without java:

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jndi, wildfly-11

i'm currently deploying a .war webservice into a Wildfly 11 application server.

The problem is, im dealing with some legacy code where JNDI names are accessed with things like

@Resource(name = "xpto/myStringValue")
private String myString;

I have tried configuring the "standalone.xml" file with

```
  <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:naming:2.0">
            <bindings>
                <simple name="xpto/myStringValue" value="abcdefgh" type="java.lang.String"/>
            </bindings>
  </subsystem>
```

But Wildfly keeps telling me

"Invalid binding name, name must start with one of [java:global, java:jboss, java:/]"

Does anyone know how can i solve this situation without changing the JNDI name on the java code?

Thanks a lot